# Como/por que fazer encadeamento de variaveis com operador = (igualdade)?

Tags: javascript, variáveis

As vezes me deparo com essas declarações encadeadas no source algumas bibliotecas e normalmente são muitas declarações encadeadas. Por exemplo:

```
var foo = foo2 = foo3 = 'foovalue';
```

No entanto eu nunca consegui entender o sentido disso e muito menos um uso prático.

Certa vez eu achei conveniente fazer um atalho para uma declaração:

```
var e = window.counter = 0;
```

Isso só pra não ter que repetir `window.counter` nas minhas condicionais. Até funcionou só que o no decorrer do script, usar esse atalho não atualizava o valor de `window.counter`.

Em fim, estou buscando uma luz sobre essa prática.

Comment: Uai cara, se você tem 1 for dentro de outro... É o uso mais rápido que me vem na cabeça.

Comment: Isto: `var foo = foo2 = foo3 = 'foovalue';` apenas cria a variável `foo` no âmbito léxico actual (i.e. função), é bom que já tenha declarado as variáveis `foo2` e `foo3` antes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse operador serve para atribuir mais de uma variável ao mesmo tempo, nem mais nem menos. É difícil pensar num uso prático assim, no abstrato, mas eu diria que se você precisa inicializar várias variáveis com o mesmo valor num algoritmo complexo, sendo que cada uma dessas variáveis vai evoluir independentemente, esse seria um uso adequado:

```
var inicio = fim = atual = 10;
while ( ... ) {
    if ( lista[inicio-1] <= lista[atual] )
        inicio--;
    if ( lista[fim+1] >= lista[atual] )
        fim++;
}
// o intervalo [inicio,fim] está ordenado (em relação ao atual)
```

Outra possibilidade é quando se quer atualizar mais de uma estrutura de dados com o mesmo valor (pode ser necessário, caso duas ou mais bibliotecas diferentes estejam atuando sobre o mesmo objeto):

```
x.atual = y.selecionado = z.emFoco = { ... };
```

Etc. O ponto-chave aqui é que são variáveis independentes, que podem em outras circunstâncias ter valores diferentes uma da outra, mas num determinado momento é desejável que todas possuam um mesmo valor. Se um único valor é necessário, é preferível usar uma variável só (delegando o acesso a ela através de funções acessoras, se necessário).

```
// Leitura
function e() { return window.counter; }

// Ou leitura-escrita
function e(v) { return v !== undefined ? window.counter = v : window.counter; }

// Uso
var x = e();
e(10);
```

P.S. A semântica do operador encadeado - caso isso não esteja claro - é atribuir a *todas* as variáveis à esquerda do último `=` o valor à direita dele.

Comment: agora entendi porque window.counter não atualizada. Na verdade não era um atalho, rs. Existe outra possibilidade mais sintática para fazer a mesma coisa?

Comment: @ropbla9 Um atalho, para que uma variável ao ser atualizada modifique outra? Não, o que eu faço é uma função acessora: `function e() { return window.counter; }` e quando preciso usar: `e()`. Mas essa bem que seria uma funcionalidade interessante pra se ter...

Comment: fantástico, bravo!